# Material UI font size is not responsive

Tags: material-ui, responsive-design

I've created the website using material UI components such as autocomplete boxes, tabs, and buttons but now I've found that the components are responsive but the text is not.
For example, I have an Autocomplete component that shrinks as per the change in width but the font size remains 14px throughout.

Autocomplete Component:-

```
<Autocomplete
  disablePortal
  defaultValue={"xyz"}
  options={symbols}
  sx={{ width: 300 }}
  onChange={handleChange}
  renderInput={(params) => (
    <TextField
      {...params}
      label="Symbols"
      inputProps={{
        ...params.inputProps,
        value: (params.inputProps.value || "").toUpperCase(),
      }}
    />
  )}
/>
```

How can I make the text of the components also responsive?

[Uneven font size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z738X.png)

I've tried using ThemeProvider to update the typography font size but nothing happened cause I haven't used the Typography component instead used components like - Tabs, Buttons, and all of which use text.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Community I've added the code for one of my components, let me know if I need to provide more details. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To have responsive font sizes, you need to wrap your theme in `responsiveFontSizes` when you export it. Below is an example:

```
import { createTheme, responsiveFontSizes } from "@mui/material/styles";

const customTheme = createTheme({
  // your theme
  },
});

export default responsiveFontSizes(customTheme);
```

This will make font sizes responsive throughout your app, and sizes will depend on the break points.